# Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type 'Entities' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization

Tags: c#, json, controller, .net-6.0, mediatr

I have this post method in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<AddClientAppSettingResponse> Post(AddClientAppSettingCommand mysetting)
    => Mediator.Send(mysetting);
```

My post method accept an `AddClientAppSettingCommand` model as you can see:

```
public class AddClientAppSettingCommand : IRequest<AddClientAppSettingResponse>
{
        public ClientAppSettings Setting { get; set; }

        public AddClientAppSettingCommand(ClientAppSettings setting)
        {
            Setting = setting;
        }
}
```

Here are my model classes:

```
public class ClientAppSettings : BaseEntity
{
        public ClientAppSettings(string userId) : base($"ClientAppSettings/{userId}")
        {
        }

        public bool LightTheme { get; set; }
        public OrderSettings Order { get; set; }
        public NotchSettings Notch { get; set; }
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        public bool ApplyCommissionInPortfolio { get; set; }
        public bool UseClosingPriceInPortfolioTotalValue { get; set; }
        public bool ShowNotifications { get; set; } = true;
        public bool NoSleep { get; set; } = true;
        public bool NoBalance { get; set; } = false;
        public bool DataTracker { get; set; } = false;
        public bool UserStatusBarToUp { get; set; } = false;
        public bool PortfolioBasedOnLastPositivePeriod { get; set; } = false;
}

public class OrderSettings
{
        public long BuyQuantity { get; set; }
        public long SellQuantity { get; set; }
        public float Tick { get; set; }
        public string TickType { get; set; }
        public bool PriceFromHeadline { get; set; }
        public bool OrderConfirmation { get; set; }
        public bool DivideOrderToMultiple { get; set; }
}

public class NotchSettings
{
        public bool Up { get; set; }
        public bool Down { get; set; }
}
```

But when I call my API using postman with these values

```
{
   "setting":{
      "LightTheme":true,
      "Order":{
         "BuyQuantity":"1",
         "SellQuantity":"1",
         "Tick":"1.0",
         "TickType":"asas",
         "PriceFromHeadline":true,
         "OrderConfirmation":true,
         "DivideOrderToMultiple":true
      },
      "Notch":{
         "Up":true,
         "Down":true
      },
      "PageSize":"10",
      "ApplyCommissionInPortfolio":true,
      "UseClosingPriceInPortfolioTotalValue":true,
      "ShowNotifications":true,
      "NoSleep":true,
      "NoBalance":true,
      "DataTracker":true,
      "UserStatusBarToUp":true,
      "PortfolioBasedOnLastPositivePeriod":true
   }
}
```

I get this error

> Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type 'domain.Entities.ClientAppSettings' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization. Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object. The match can be case-insensitive

As a note I use MediatR for CQRS ,I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68484907/error-each-parameter-in-constructor-must-bind-to-an-object-property-or-field-on) but it didn't work .I put a `[JsonConstructor]` on

```
 public AddClientAppSettingCommand(ClientAppSettings setting)
        {
            Setting = setting;
        }
```

But it didn't work .and my variable `setting` is null

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you need a parameterless constructor for api input parameter

```
public class AddClientAppSettingCommand : IRequest<AddClientAppSettingResponse>
{
        public ClientAppSettings Setting { get; set; }

        public AddClientAppSettingCommand() {}
       

        public AddClientAppSettingCommand(ClientAppSettings setting)
        {
            Setting = setting;
        }
}
```

and the same for settings

```
public class ClientAppSettings : BaseEntity
{
public ClientAppSettings(){}
      
}
```

Comment: Hi Serge .I did ,but I get the same error

Comment: @EhsanAkbar and the same for settings

Comment: Thank you Serge ,It works .Thanks a lot.Would you please give me a detail about what was the problem and why we should define a constructor with no parameters for those objects .thanks

Comment: @EhsanAkbar because the way a controlle create an input parameter. At first it creates an empty object, after this  it trys to assign to this object properties properties from request object. So to create an empty object it needs the constructor.

Comment: Also, check if any of your properties are nullable, that makes a difference as well.