# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject defaults to first Enum item

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I have the following data object.

```
public class Response<T> where T : MyBaseDTO
    {
     public bool result
        {
            get; set;
        }

     public List<Message> messages
        {
            get; set;
        }
     public List<T> data 
        {
            get; set;
        }
}
     public class Message
        {      
            public Message(MessageTypeEnum type)
            {
                this.typeEnum = type;
            }
    
            public string type
            {
                get
                {
                    return typeEnum.ToString();
                }
         
            }
    
            public MessageTypeEnum typeEnum
            {
                get; set;
            }
          
           public int index
            {
                get; set;
            }
            
            public string field
            {
                get; set;
            }
            public string code
            {
                get; set;
            }
           public string message
             {
              get; set;
            }
           public string messageValue
            {
             get; set;
             }
        public enum MessageTypeEnum
        {
            WARNING,
            INFO,
            ERROR
        }
```

When I use RestSharp to call the API, the deserialized Data is null with following error(Content contains correct response in string):

```
" ErrorMessage "Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type 'Response.Message' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization."
```

I found the following post and added empty constructor to my object.

[Error: Each parameter in constructor must bind to an object property or field on deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68484907/error-each-parameter-in-constructor-must-bind-to-an-object-property-or-field-on)

```
    public class Message
{
    public Message()
    {
    }
    public Message(MessageTypeEnum type)
    {
        this.typeEnum = type;
    }

    public string type
    {
        get
        {
            return typeEnum.ToString();
        }

    }

    public MessageTypeEnum typeEnum
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public int index
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string field
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string code
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string message
        {
          get; set;
         }
   public string messageValue
         {
          get; set;
          }
    public enum MessageTypeEnum
    {
        WARNING,
        INFO,
        ERROR
    }
```

Added empty constructor resolved my issue with RestSharp. However I just noticed it failed some unit tests in my other project that uses Message Object.

Here is the code

```
using var reader = new StreamReader(result.ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStream());
body = reader.ReadToEnd();

Response<Test> responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<Test>>(body);
```

"body" looks like something below which is expected.

```
body    "{\"result\":true,\"messages\":[{\"type\":\"ERROR\",\"index\":0,\"field\":\"ID\",\"code\":\"MISSING-ID\",\"message\":\"The entry is incomplete.",\"messageValue\":null}],\"data\":[{\"....
```

However, after the deserialization, "Type" became WARNING instead ERROR and hence it failed the unit test.

Looks like it defaults to first one of the Enum.

```
public enum MessageTypeEnum
        {
            WARNING,
            INFO,
            ERROR
        }
```

Does anyone knows what's going on here and how to fix the issue?

Comment: The default value for an enum is 0, which in your case is warning. Your body appears to only contain a type property but on your data model it is a read-only property so it will be ignored, leaving it the default value.

Comment: Your json is not valid and I couldn't find a Response<Test> class that you use for deserialiazation. Can you pls fix this and create an example we could test?

Comment: Try making the default constructor private, or protected, and then create a JsonSerializerSettings object with ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor.  Maybe this will resolve your unit test issues, if you need for that class not to be publicly creatable in that fashion?

Comment: @ScottyD0nt Yes looks like that way, what are possible ways to resolve the this?

Comment: @NathanM I tried that. Make it private resolve the unit test and then I try=ied to apply .AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor to RestSharp. Couldn't get it work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have type as string too, you have to fix your Message costructor by adding attribute

```
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Message(MessageTypeEnum type)
    {
        this.typeEnum = type;
    }
```

after this everything is working properly

Comment: Thanks. I had issues after added [JsonConstructor] and realized it was referencing to System.Text.Json. Looks like the issue is resolved after I referenced it to using Newtonsoft.Json; I will run a few more tests.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not complete and your JSON example is malformed, so I am unable to provide an example with your exact code. That said, you should be able to suss out the details you need to fix your particular issue.

First, when you are deserializing to a class you must have an empty constructor as required by the deserializer. The deserializer will not be passing any parameters to your constructor, so you can't depend on them.

Second, to read/write a class property it must have both a `get` and `set`. The deserializer will not be able to fully work with properties that do not have both `get` and `set`.

---

**One possible solution**, is to create a string property that contains both `get` and `set`, and then create an additional property with only the `get` that is typed to the Enum.

The root object is basically your Response object, but as you didn't provide that code I made the RootObject.

```
 public class RootObject
    {
        public bool result { get; set; }
        public Message[] messages { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Message
    {
        // string property to allow deserialization
        public string type
        {
            get; set;
        }

        // read only property typed to the enum that will
        // refer to the 'type' property for conversion to the enum
        public MessageTypeEnum typeEnum
        {
            get
            {
                switch (type.ToUpper())
                {
                    case nameof(MessageTypeEnum.WARNING):
                        return MessageTypeEnum.WARNING;
                    case nameof(MessageTypeEnum.INFO):
                        return MessageTypeEnum.INFO;
                    case nameof(MessageTypeEnum.ERROR):
                        return MessageTypeEnum.ERROR;
                    default:
                        return MessageTypeEnum.UNKNOWN;
                        // return UNKNOWN or throw an out of range exception?
                }
            }
        }

        public int index
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public string field
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public string code
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public enum MessageTypeEnum
        {
            WARNING,
            INFO,
            ERROR
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated the code with complete Response object. If I use typeEnum like yours. How should I change my Message constructor public Message(MessageTypeEnum type)? Because typeEnum is read only now.

Comment: Your constructor should be defined as a parameter-less constructor (e.g. `public Message() { }`). Or not defined explicitly by you, in which case .Net will generate a parameter-less constructor behind the scenes for you.